# How to uninstall rvm, ruby, rails and gems. I'm getting errors on Mavericks

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, rvm, osx-mavericks, ruby-2.1

I'm new on Ruby on Rails and I have some problems with configuration. I don't know what to do. I installed many times ruby, rails and Gems because report problems.
I read a lot of questions on stack overflow and nothing for solve.
I try now uninstalling everything and I have some errors when I trying to remove Gems, :

I report some problems on the terminal and I don't know how to send a log, etc..
It's that correct for uninstall:

Remove Gems: `$ gem clean`
-Uninstall ruby: `$ rvm uninstall ruby` (#this will uninstall all ruby's installed?)
or need:
-Uninstall by version:

```
$ rvm uninstall 2.1.0
```

and others version 2.0.0 and 2.1.1

-Uninstall rvm:

```
$ rvm repair
$ rvm cleanup
$ rvm implode
```

and for now install everything again!?

When I try I have this:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Romenig:~ romenig$ gem clean
Cleaning up installed gems...
Clean Up Complete
MacBook-Pro-de-Romenig:~ romenig$ cd ~
MacBook-Pro-de-Romenig:~ romenig$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
MacBook-Pro-de-Romenig:~ romenig$ ruby lis
ruby: No such file or directory -- lis (LoadError)
MacBook-Pro-de-Romenig:~ romenig$ ruby list
ruby: No such file or directory -- list (LoadError)
MacBook-Pro-de-Romenig:~ romenig$ ruby list
ruby: No such file or directory -- list (LoadError)
MacBook-Pro-de-Romenig:~ romenig$ rvm ruby list
Please note that `rvm ruby ...` was removed, try `ruby list ` or `rvm all do ruby list ` instead. ( see: 'rvm usage' )
MacBook-Pro-de-Romenig:~ romenig$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.5.3)
CFPropertyList (2.2.0)
libxml-ruby (2.6.0)
nokogiri (1.5.6)
sqlite3 (1.3.7)
MacBook-Pro-de-Romenig:~ romenig$ gem clean
Cleaning up installed gems...
Clean Up Complete
MacBook-Pro-de-Romenig:~ romenig$ rvm uninstall ruby
Please note that `rvm ruby ...` was removed, try `ruby  ` or `rvm all do ruby  ` instead. ( see: 'rvm usage' )
MacBook-Pro-de-Romenig:~ romenig$ rvm list

rvm rubies

   ruby-2.0.0-p353 [ x86_64 ]
 * ruby-2.1.0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.1 [ missing bin/ruby ]
   ruby-2.1.1-rails [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

MacBook-Pro-de-Romenig:~ romenig$ rvm all do uninstall ruby
You must be root to run this tool.
You must be root to run this tool.
You must be root to run this tool.
You must be root to run this tool.
MacBook-Pro-de-Romenig:~ romenig$ sudo rvm all do uninstall ruby
Password:
URL is not uninstallable: ruby
URL is not uninstallable: ruby
URL is not uninstallable: ruby
URL is not uninstallable: ruby
MacBook-Pro-de-Romenig:~ romenig$ rvm uninstall 2.1.0
ruby-2.1.0 - #removing rubies/ruby-2.1.0.......................................|
Error running '__rvm_rm_rf /Users/romenig/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/romenig/.rvm/log/1395265139_ruby-2.1.0/remove.rubies.log
rm: /Users/romenig/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/tzinfo-0.3.39/test/ts_all.rb: Permission denied
rm: /Users/romenig/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/tzinfo-0.3.39/test: Permission denied
rm: /Users/romenig/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/tzinfo-0.3.39/tzinfo.gemspec: Permission denied
rm: /Users/romenig/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/tzinfo-0.3.39: Directory not empty
rm: /Users/romenig/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems: Directory not empty
rm: /Users/romenig/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0: Directory not empty
rm: /Users/romenig/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems: Directory not empty
rm: /Users/romenig/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby: Directory not empty
rm: /Users/romenig/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib: Directory not empty
rm: /Users/romenig/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0: Directory not empty
++ typeset ret=1
++ rvm_debug '__rvm_rm_rf error removing target dir '\''/Users/romenig/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0'\''.'
++ ((  0  ))
++ return 0
++ return 1
```

My RMV INFO:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Romenig:~ romenig$ rvm info

system:

  system:
    uname:       "Darwin MacBook-Pro-de-Romenig.local 13.1.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.1.0: Thu Jan 16 19:40:37 PST 2014; root:xnu-2422.90.20~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64"
    system:      "osx/10.9/x86_64"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)"
    zsh:         "/bin/zsh => zsh 5.0.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.0)"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.25.20 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "3 hours 21 minutes 47 seconds ago"
    path:         "/Users/romenig/.rvm"

  homes:
    gem:          "not set"
    ruby:         "not set"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/usr/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/usr/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/usr/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/usr/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/romenig/.rvm/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     ""
    GEM_PATH:     ""
    MY_RUBY_HOME: ""
    IRBRC:        ""
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""


$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.5.3)
CFPropertyList (2.2.0)
libxml-ruby (2.6.0)
nokogiri (1.5.6)
sqlite3 (1.3.7)

rvm gemset list

gemsets for system (found in /Users/romenig/.rvm/gems/system)
=> (default)
   *
```

Answer (score 23):

Just delete rvm folder (to remove rvm, rubies, gems etc.)

```
rm -rf ~/.rvm
```

or

```
rvm implode
```